# Node.js кушает много памяти

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, memory

Имеется скрипт :

```
var timer = 0;

function save_price() {

var fs               = require("fs"),
  request            = require("request"),
  config             = require('./server.config.js').config,
  IGetMarketPrices_URL = config.IGetMarketPrices_URL,
  myData = {"response":{"success":0,"message":"You can only request this page every 300 seconds per API key. Try again in 176 seconds."}};

  timer = setInterval(function(){ 

  request({
      url: IGetMarketPrices_URL,
      json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          myData = body;

        fs.writeFile('../var/www/prices.json', JSON.stringify(myData, null, 4), function(err) {
            if(err)
              console.log(err);
            else
              console.log("JSON saved to " + '../var/www/prices.json');

        }); 
        fs.writeFile('prices.json', JSON.stringify(myData, null, 4), function(err) {
            if(err)
              console.log(err);
            else
              console.log("JSON saved to " + 'prices.json');

        }); 

      }
  });

   }, 10800000);//10800000 =  каждые 3 часов

  //clearInterval(timer);
  //save_price();
}

save_price();
```

**Внимание, вопрос:** почему скрипт кушает 105 мб за 8 часов аптайма, хотя там только один цикл выполняющийся раз в 3 часа, возможно ли как-то модернмзмровать?

*`Если код кривой, буду рад увидеть поправки, спасибо.`*

Вот скрин:
[image: Скрин демона на сервере]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

node.js забирает внешнюю память, пока не достигнет максимально разрешенного размера кучи (примерно 1,5Гб, если память не изменяет), либо пока система не начнет требовать память обратно (перестанет давать).

Чтобы проверить, происходит ли утечка памяти, можно добавить следующий кусок:

```
setInterval(function(){ //из Вашего кода
    global.gc();
    console.log('Memory usage:', process.memoryUsage());
//остальной код
```

Запустить node.js с флагом `--expose-gc`, смотреть на вывод (значение `heapUsed`).

Если значение `heapUsed` колеблется в определенных пределах, то значит утечки нет, и 105 Мб "отъедаются" node.js, просто чтобы реже делать сборку мусора. Но судя по этому коду, утечек быть не должно, так что можно не волноваться.

По части кода:

- как минимум, объявление и `require` переменный лучше вынести за пределы функции
- `JSON.stringify()` проще сохранить в переменную, чтобы не делать его 2 раза
- не совсем понимаю, зачем вообще переменная `myData`, учитывая, что она инициируется 1 раз и нигде не используется (присвоение `body` в `myData`, с последующим `JSON.stringify()` смысла не несет в данном случае)
- возможно имеет смысл добавить логирование ошибки выполнения запроса
- точно нужен отложенный на значение интервала первый вызов запроса?

Comment: Спасибо большое, память колеблется от 100 до 127, больше не кушает, значит утечки нету. Но у меня есть 2 сервера один и тот же код что там, что там, и вот: на одном скрипт кушает 29 мб, а на втором 127, в чем может быть проблема ? За советы спасибо вам огромное, я ими воспользовался.

Comment: Если эти показатели памяти - значение `heapUsed`, то единственное, что могу предположить - разные версии node.js (при абсолютно одинаковых скриптах). Но это что-то слишком странное. Если же это - размер занимаемой процессом памяти, то скорее всего на первом просто меньше свободной памяти, поэтому node.js ужимает кучу.

Comment: Видимо так и есть, на сервере , где кушает 29 там 1гб оперативной памяти, а там где 100-127 - 2гб оперативной памяти.